# Matplotlib boxplot: conf_intervals length not compatible with x

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am trying to integrate confidence intervals into my boxplots. I tried creating it like the documentation suggested:

```
plt.boxplot(datablindup[1:], notch=True, conf_intervals=errdouble)
```

datablindup has 5 columns of data, and it works fine if I leave out the notch and conf_intervals stuff. Errdouble is a (2,5) array containing the confidence intervals:

```
[[ 13.74278924  17.07127078 207.60434675 291.80790981 852.09260668]
 [ 13.74278924  17.07127078 207.60434675 291.80790981 852.09260668]]
```

However, I always get the error message "conf_intervals length not compatible with x". What does that mean? I only have 5 xticks from 1 to 5 on the x axis...

Comment: Please provide `datablindup` or at least its shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very straight-forward, just change the shape of the `errdouble` by transposing it.

```
plt.boxplot(datablindup[1:], notch=True, conf_intervals=errdouble.T)
```

The shape expected by conf_intervals - in your case - is **(5, 2)** *not* (2, 5).

Comment: Worked like a charm, however, my confidence interval array is wrong :) I have to add the means.